# Unable to open Cypress tool

Tags: automation, cypress

Unable to open cypress test runner I have  tried opening by using npx cypress open  but it is not working now

[image]

Comment: As the error says, there is some issue with your `cypress.json` file. Please check that file.

Comment: Thanks i  reinstalled it is working now